# Learning Construct 2

Tags: html, construct-2

I am keen in learning construct 2. Which website or tutorial is to get started in working on construct 2. I am pretty keen to learn... Would really useful to many people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best resource for construct 2 is the [scirra website](http://www.scirra.com) itself. There you can find [the beginner's guide,](http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/37/beginners-guide-to-construct-2) the manual, as well as plenty of other tutorials and an active forum with a helpful community where you can ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

On the Scirra Website there is also a FAQ for many functions. This Post for example is very useful:

[Useful FAQ Code Examples](http://www.scirra.com/forum/how-do-ifrequently-asked-questions_topic45416.html)